# Site down after VM restart

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machines

I have a standard WordPress installation on GCP. I needed to edit the php.ini file, which I did. And, then restarted my VM, so that all services such as PHP, Apache etc. also get restarted.

However, the site is now no longer accessible. Neither from the domain name, nor using the external IP address. Any ideas on how to bring it back up?

In deployments, I do see a warning icon, but it's impossible to figure out what the issue is, and how to fix it.

[Deployments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HRBD.png)

[VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEu1v.png)

Comment: Connect via ssh and read the logs? The IP listed in GCP answers on SSH.

Answer (score 1):

Is the VM's IP address ephemeral or reserved?

The IP address in your screenshot `35.228.196.69` does not match the DNS resource record `34.88.197.250` for the domain `portfoliodoc.app`.

Consult this guide, reserve an IP address and update your DNS server.

[Reserve a static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address)

After updating DNS with the correct IP address you will have to wait for DNS to propagate (minutes to hours).